# Make PHPStorm always logged in to FTP

Tags: php, phpstorm

Every time i upload file to FTP with PHPStorm, it says 'Logging in..' and then uploads files. Everything works OK, but this 'Logging in..' takes bunch of time. Can it somehow stay always logged in?

Comment: It's a valid question with a valid answer, if you go to the request you'll see that it was upvoted by 140 users. How does it make it non constructive?

Comment: Recently I have updated java and faced with same problem ( before it was ok ).
It sounds like magic but the following action helped me out: just  click Tools -> Deployment -> Brows Remote Host. Now all works without reconnections

Comment: You can use local port forward: http://www.v3k.net/en/phpstorm-faster-deploy

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not yet, please vote for this feature:

- [Option not to break the FTP/SFTP connection (keep alive)](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-674)